# How do I specify a path prefix when calling the delta method in Dropbox Core Api on Android?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, delta

The [docs](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/index.html) for Dropbox Android core API show the delta method to be:

```
public DropboxAPI.DeltaPage<DropboxAPI.Entry> delta(java.lang.String cursor)
                                         throws DropboxException
```

However, this returns all the delta entries for the entire dropbox account. I only want delta entries for a specific directory.

The [docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#delta) for the web core API show that delta can in fact specify a path_prefix. If present, this parameter filters the response to only include entries at or under the specified path.

Is there anyway to specify a path prefix using the Android Dropbox core API delta method?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android SDK doesn't have support for this parameter built in. You would need to add this to the SDK yourself.